# c++ integer type automatic 64 bit

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using `size_t` for unsigned integer in my code. It has an advantage, if my computer support 64 bit, `size_t` will be `unsigned long long int`, otherwise, it is `unsigned int`. My code can run on both 32 bit and 64 bit platform.

Is there a similar signed integer? If the platform only support 32 bit, it is `int`, if the platform support 64 bit, it is `long long int`.

I can achieve this by setting a flag:

```
#ifdef USE_INT64
    #define MY_INT int
#else
    #define MY_INT long long int
#endif
```

Then use `MY_INT`. However I need to define `USE_INT64` and include this header for all my code. If there is something similar to `size_t`, it will be great.

Comment: Use `uint64_t` instead maybe?

Comment: There is a whole bunch of integer types in cstdint (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint). Pick an appropiate one.

Comment: As of C++11, *all* conforming C++ compilers support 64-bit integers. Given that, it might be reasonable to want to use 32-bit integers on some systems and 64-bit integers on others -- but first you should define how you want to make that choice. See also the `<cstdint>` standard header, which defines integer types with exact widths as well as "fast" and "least" types with *at least* specified widths. `int_fast32_t` might be what you want.

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` is a signed type, and is likely to be 32-bits on "32-bit" systems and 64 bits on "64-bit" systems, but I wouldn't use it for this purpose. It's the type of the result of pointer subtraction, and the only guarantee is that it's at least 17 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to tie your types directly to address width, then the types you are looking for are called `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`. They are inherited from C standard library through `<cstdint>`.

Type `size_t` is not guaranteed to have the same size as pointer (it is smaller in general case), meaning its usability for that purpose is platform-specific. (Read: even though it will work everywhere, it is conceptually wrong.)

Of course, the real question here is whether there's a good underlying reason to tie your integer type to address width. If not, a better idea would be to define your types directly through `uintNN_t`/`intNN_t` typedefs and forget about `size_t` and such.

Answer (score 1):

There is a corresponding signed type [`ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) that is defined for taking the difference between two pointers. It should be the same size as a pointer, just as `size_t` is.

Comment: "Same size as pointer" is `uintptr_t`. An implementation can decide to make `ptrdiff_t` *larger* than pointer to allow user to subtract any pointers. `size_t`  is generaly *smaller* than pointer.

Comment: @AnT I don't think I've seen an implementation where `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` is a different size than a pointer, but I forgot about `intptr_t` entirely. +1 on your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::make_signed` to get the exact signed analog to what `std::size_t` is for unsigned:

```
using fancy_signed = std::make_signed<std::size_t>::type;
```